# Can you add Visual Studio Code shortcuts to Google Chrome on Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio

I use a lot of handy shortcuts in VS Code and often find myself trying to use them in Google Chrome (and other programs as well). For example, copy line down → `alt`+`shift`+`arrow down` or remove paragraph/whole line without cutting it → `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `L`.
Is there a way to introduce these shortcuts to Google Chrome?

Comment: Is it on Windows?

Comment: @harrymc yes, it is, I corrected the question.